# Android Studio: Can I use android's DeviceControlActivity.java class or is it too old already? Are there other BLE classes I can use?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

There are some other methods from android but I think it es easier to use DeviceControlActivity.java class.

Comment: You could read the code to understand one way to use BLE, but I wouldn't copy paste it into my project.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your issue. In terms of what APIs you can use android studio gives a lot of documentation. You can use their device control activity and customise it to your needs.